# Should I bother with cross browser compatibility if i'll be just using nwjs?

Tags: nw.js

And should I also bother myself with the semantics of each html tag I use?

It somehow bothers me that i'll be shooting myself in the foot if I developed an html5/javascrippt app that doesn't conform to the web standard and can only run specifically with nwjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you develop for the desktop app only. You shouldn't worry about the compatibility issue and can use all the new features in new Chrome.